# Share a String Variable Between AppleScript & Objective C

Tags: objective-c, applescript, applescript-objc

I have perhaps 1% `Objective C` knowledge, and am more comfortable using `AppleScript` for small tasks.

I'm developing an app that requires a more attractive alert window though, so I have started to learn more about `AppleScriptObjC`.

**My question is**, how do I get my AppleScript variable '*serialNumber*', which is set to a string from the clipboard that will be something like "* 1234567890 *", into the Objective C side of things so that I can display the string through the label object?

I've already got my label set up as

'*property serialNumberLabel: missing value*'

I just don't know how to transfer the variable between the two languages, so that I can set the serialNumberLabel value to the string currently stored in the serialNumber variable.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript strings are implicitly bridged to `NSString`, so you can write

```
set serialNumber to the clipboard
serialNumberLabel’s setStringValue:serialNumber
```

In the opposite direction you need to coerce the `NSString` object to `text`

```
set serialNumber to serialNumberLabel’s stringValue() as text
```

Comment: Hi Vadian, thanks for your reply.  When I add 'serialNumberLabel's setStringValue:serialNumber' to my AppleScript code, I get an error saying 'Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token.' Should that line be going inside the AppleScript 'on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)' code block, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes the script vadian posted like all scripts should be used inside a block (unless the blocks are included in the snippet.) like  applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification) which will be triggered when the application launches. so if you paste the script he supplied you with inside the block - When the application launches it will read your clipboard setting its contents to variable "serialNumber" then the Label "serialNumberLabel" will set its stringValue (its text) to "serialNumber"